How to Capture Network on Mobile App is running?
In the website, we can check request and response from Network tab on Devtools

How can I capture the network on mobile app is running?
(I don't have app's source code)
Thank you

You can do two different things:

Utilize an HTTP proxy: I like using Fiddler. Install Fiddler on a machine, allow incoming connections from other devices, and then configure your phone to use this proxy as the system HTTP proxy.

Use Connectify (or similar) to set up a wireless access hotspot: Run Wireshark on the machine hosting the hotspot to inspect the packets.

Perform a man-in-the-middle attack on yourself (on your mobile): Basically, do 2) but if needed, set up SSL stripping or use tools like mitmproxy to handle HTTPS traffic.


